# how to resize google map container according to the circle's radius?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working with google maps v3.

And its integrated successfully with my website.

But i need to resize the google maps according to the circle's radius. Means i need to show the google map covered by that circle.

Right now my container's size is height :600px; and width : 700px;

and circle's radius is 10000 i.e 10km.

but i need to increase the container's size if i increase the radius. and i don't know how to do that.

Can anyone please help me ?

My google map's code is as below :

```
 var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
 var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.838265, 151.206481);

var mapOptions = {
  center: myLatLng,
  zoom: 12,
  maxZoom: 12,
  minZoom: 12,
  disableDefaultUI: true,
   draggable: false,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
  var map = new google.maps.Map($('#map_canvas')[0], mapOptions);

  var cmarker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map,
  position: myLatLng
});

    // Add circle overlay and bind to marker
var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
  map: map,
  radius: 10000,    // 10 km in metres
  fillColor: '#AA0000'
});
circle.bindTo('center', cmarker, 'position');
```

Please help me..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want the map at zoom level 12 to just fit a 10 km  circle centered at -33.838265, 151.206481?

Comment: yes but i want the map_canvas div to fit a circle.

Comment: You want the _div_ to be a circle?

Comment: no it should be square or rectangle. That's what i don't know that how to set height and width according to radius ?

Comment: To just fit a circle, it will be square.

Comment: thats fine. have u find out any solution ?

Comment: What have you tried?  It is certainly possible, I don't have any reason to do that though.

Answer (score 0):

Possible workflow:

1. retrieve the `bounds` of the circle(the radius is irrelavant here, because the real size of the circle will depend on the center)
2. convert the southwest and northeast to pixels(you may use the functions at http://qfox.nl/notes/116 to achieve it)
3. the half of the difference between the x-pixels will be the width and the half of the difference between the y-pixels the height. Resize the map-div to these values
4. trigger the resize-event of the map
5. re-center the map. Don't use the center-latLng of the circle, because you must center the map at the geometric center of the circle(which is not equal to the geographic center).
   calculation of the center-pixel:

   ```
   x: southwestX + halfOfWidth
   y: northeastY + halfOfHeight
   ```

   convert this point into a LatLng and set the center.

Result:http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/Bqr3Y/